# How to operate on an Applescript range reference object to determine the number of rows?

Tags: excel, applescript, range

A range of cells can be returned as an Excel object from a line like:

```
set the_range_to_measure_size to used range
```

And a line like:

```
get address of the_range_to_measure_size
-- >result "$A$1:$D$56"
```

will return a range as text

What is the simplest way to return the 'dimensions' of a range object i.e.

- width (in columns)
- height (in rows)
- start row (as integer or string)
- start column (as integer or string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `range` class entry in the [Excel Applescript dictionary](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/113891):

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    get count of columns of used range of active sheet
    get count of rows of used range of active sheet
    get first row index of used range of active sheet
    get first column index of used range of active sheet
end tell
```